# how to avoid duplicate entries

Tags: php, sql

I created a form on my website where the user can create an account. I save everything into a database connected to a website.
This is how I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    CID int(9) not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Email VARCHAR(100) not null,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(42) not null,
    Password VARCHAR(42) not null,
    Phone VARCHAR(42)
);
```

Since users would use the email and password to later login to the website, I don't want duplicated email entries.
Now my question is should I make column email unique inside my table or should I check if the inputted email already exists in the database (with PHP)? Is there even any difference?

Comment: it depends on how did your database set up. i think that query that returns value is better than query wich returns an error. and you will have an error with unique indices. or you will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the email and username as unique for example

```
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
    `CID` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `CustomerName` VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
    `Password` VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
    `Phone` VARCHAR(42) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`CID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Email` (`Email`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `CustomerName` (`CustomerName`)
);
```

of course you must also check it in your application, but this will prevent it.

Comment: this time I was faster then bill ;-)